# Django. Add, edit and delete on django

Tags: django, django-models, request, foreign-keys

Tell me, please, what will the function for adding, editing and deleting listings look like? First, how to correctly register the current user in this function? Secondly, how to ensure that only the current user can delete and edit listings? At the moment, this can be done by anyone, even an unregistered user.

```
def listing_delete(request, listing_id):
        listing = Listing.objects.get(id=listing_id)
        listing.delete()
        return redirect('index')

def listing_edit(request, listing_id):  
    form = ListingForm(instance = Listing.objects.get(id = listing_id))
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ListingForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = Listing.objects.get(id = listing_id))    
        if form.is_valid():                 
            listing = form.save()
            return redirect('listing', listing_id)
    else:
        ListingForm(instance=Listing.objects.get(id = listing_id))

    return render(request, 'listings/listing_edit.html', {'form': form})

def listing_add(request):
    form = ListingForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ListingForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            listing = form.save(commit=False)
            listing.realtor = request.user
            listing.save()
            return redirect('dashboard')

    return render(request, 'listings/listing_add.html', {'form': form})
```

I understand that listing.realtor = request.user is wrong, because there must be an instance of a realtor, but I didn’t understand how to do it correctly.

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    realtor = models.ForeignKey(Realtor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Риэлтор')
    region = models.CharField(default="Чуйская", max_length=100, verbose_name='Область')
    city = models.CharField(default="Бишкек", max_length=100, verbose_name='Город')
    district = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, verbose_name='Район')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    address = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, verbose_name='Адрес')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Описание') 
    stage = models.IntegerField(blank=True, verbose_name='Этажность')
    rooms = models.IntegerField(blank=True, verbose_name='Количество комнат')   
    garage = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, verbose_name='Гараж')
    sqmt = models.IntegerField(blank=True, verbose_name='Площадь')
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, verbose_name='Цена')
    photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Основное фото')
    photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Фото 1')
    photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Фото 2')
    photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Фото 3')
    photo_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Фото 4')
    photo_5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Фото 5')
    photo_6 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Фото 6')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Публично')
    list_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True, verbose_name='Дата публикации')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Realtor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Пользователь', related_name='realtor')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name='Фото')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Описание')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Телефон')
    is_mvp = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Реэлтор месяца')
    hire_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True, verbose_name='Дата приёма на работу')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your database logic, you should set `request.user` to `listing.realtor.user`

```
def listing_add(request):
    form = ListingForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ListingForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            listing = form.save(commit=False)
            listing.realtor.user = request.user //here
            listing.save()
            return redirect('dashboard')

    return render(request, 'listings/listing_add.html', {'form': form})
```

For your second question, you can use `@login_required` decorator in order to have the only logged on users to edit, delete and add.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def method_name():
    #Logic
```

Comment: But it should be listing.realtor = request.user.realtor

Comment: What do you try to do? You cannot access realtor from user because you don't have that field in user model.

Comment: When I did this: listing.realtor = request.user.realtor - it worked. Thank's? Thank you for suggesting ;)

Comment: I would not suggest to do it because it probably makes joins and this is will create overhead. You are welcome.